# Give a command HTTP proxy auth access

Tags: linux, proxy, http, netcat

I'd like to let a command (wsimport) access a URL through an HTTP proxy with authentication.

It can be configured to use a proxy, but not with auth. I was wondering if a tool such as netcat, or any readily available Linux package, could be setup as a proxy without authentication and pass requests onto the proxy which requires authentication?

The idea being that wsimport could point at my proxy without auth and my proxy would know how to auth with the next one.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-231 ?

Comment: I have, thanks. I don't believe the example given in the top comment works.